# Is there a way of changing from user to root within a script (enter the password in the script)?

Tags: scripts, sudo

for example this script:

```
cat switch_to_root.sh
sudo -i
#here i want somehow that the script will get as parameter my root password and use it in login.
```

Comment: 1st question: why? Reason for the question: the answer depends on it. What you show is useless since it is longer to type "switch_to_root.sh" than "sudo -i". 1st remark: you use "sudo -i", not "sudo su" on Ubuntu. 2nd remark: you will not put the password inside a script. Never.

Comment: i want to allow users and not root and that they will be able to run script with root permission

Comment: @user3023559 OK, there are far better ways of doing this. In fact, what you are trying here, even if it did work, would attempt to cange the password of the `root` account. That's what the `passwd` command does. So it wouldn't log anyone in, it would just change root's password! Please [edit] your question and explain what you actually want to do. Tell us what your users should be able to run as root and we will tell you how to do it.

Comment: Then you use visudo to allow users or a group to execute that command.  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/visudo.8.html  Here are some examples: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos

Comment: for my understand this is to change the sudo file , what i want is to enter as root but from a password in a script

Comment: @user3023559 this is possible, you can write the password in the script, but it is a very, very bad idea. If you explain what you want with more detail, we can offer you a solution. The simple answer is `echo password | sudo -S` but there is almost never a good reason to do this. Please give us more detail so we can give you a clean solution.